Solana program upgrade priority fees
In Solana CLI 1.18 there is --with-compute-unit-price param on program deploy, but when looking for the same param on 'solana program upgrade' there is no such flag.
As a consequence, all of 500+ upgrade transactions are submitted without priority fees and it is currently practically impossible to upgrade the program on mainnet.
Is there any solution to this or we have to wait for new version of Solana CLI with added priority fees on program upgrade?

Is there a difference between using deploy to upgrade the program vs using upgrade?

Deploy can work on existing or create new program account, upgrade can only upgrade to the existing account. Before priority fees introduction I was always using the upgrade for the contract updates but it seems now only way on mainnet is to use deploy like @chalda suggests.

@IvanBritvic interested in how that was about the usage of upgrade as you've been used to it? Does it mean you did the write-buffer first and then upgrade or I'm missing something in the flow? Does it mean you normally are not able to process neither the one upgrade transaction with retries to get it placed on-chain without a priority fee? Just wondering, I have no more insight.

I believe you can (or should) use just the solana program deploy when you update the Solana program. That's what is needed in most cases.
The CLI help says Deploy an upgradeable program while in the code one can find more details on this point.
https://github.com/anza-xyz/agave/blob/v1.18.15/cli/src/program.rs#L1124
 Returns the instructions required to upgrade a program.
The deploy command checks if the provided program id already exists on-chain and in that case it upgrades the existing code with a new one.
The program deployment consists of two parts. One is to write data to a buffer account.

That creates new buffer account on-chain and it takes compiled code (.so file) and copies data to the buffer account. That requires multiple transactions (100s) as one Solana transaction may transfer only the limited data size (https://solana.com/docs/core/transactions#key-points).
When all data program is available on-chain then there is executed the deploy transaction (https://github.com/anza-xyz/agave/blob/v1.18.15/cli/src/program.rs#L2337) that switches the new data from buffer account being the real program executed by the program.

The CLI consists of commands

deploy a clever wrapper that gets .so program and its ID, it copies the program data on-chain and based on the on-chain state it either creates a new program or upgrades the existing one
write-buffer to create the program buffer account and load data there (first part of the deploy command functionality)
upgrade to only push the buffer account address into the executable program account and thus switch the old program to a new program (second part of the deploy command functionality when upgrading)

See

https://github.com/anza-xyz/agave/blob/v1.18.15/cli/src/program.rs#L942
https://github.com/anza-xyz/agave/blob/v1.18.15/cli/src/program.rs#L88

With that, the deploy and write-buffer commands process a large number of transactions as they load the program .so data from localhost to on-chain to a buffer account there is a good need to define the --with-compute-unit-price to get all transaction to be processed.
On the other hand the upgrade runs just one transaction (switching the program data addresses). If it fails to land only this one transaction needs to be retried. And retrying one transaction is not such a big pain. And it is a bit of internal command. (My considerations, were not checked with anybody from Agave team.)
